# Error During Bazel Build of Tensorflow (Serving tutorial): Ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, tensorflow-serving

OS: Ubuntu 16.04
bazel: 0.17.2

I am using commit : 30248e75390cd068af7af37d62ac158304436415 of serving repository. I am following the tutorial at: https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/serving_advanced

After cloning the serving repo, I use the WORKSPACE file in the current version of serving repository.
The tensorflow commit it points is downloaded correctly in the build process, but next thing I see is the following error:

> > .
> >     Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
> >     ........
> >     ERROR: /home/vaibhavs/tensorflow_serving/serving/.cache/_bazel_root/45e5a12780caa2dd1c70f796d572c44c/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/BUILD:73:1: error loading package '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/python/keras': Extension file not found. Unable to load package for '@pip_deps//:requirements.bzl': The repository could not be resolved and referenced by '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/python:no_contrib'
> >     ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow_serving/example:mnist_saved_model' failed; build aborted: error loading package '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/python/keras': Extension file not found. Unable to load package for '@pip_deps//:requirements.bzl': The repository could not be resolved
> >     INFO: Elapsed time: 23.963s
> >     INFO: 0 processes.
> >     FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (67 packages loaded)
> >         currently loading: @org_tensorflow//tensorflow/python/keras ... (2 packages)
> >     <<<

I could not find this exact error message on Google. 
Can somebody give me any pointers on what I may be missing?

Comment: Thanks for the downvote without any explicit reason :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pulling from master again - there was a bug which was fixed.

Comment: @ Gautam, Thanks for your reply. Can you also give any pointers about the bug?